# Where can I read/buy "Boys over Flowers" manga in French (or English)?

Tags: resources, boys-over-flowers

I live in the UK (but don't mind ordering online) and would like to find the manga books *Boys Over Flowers* in French (or English). I'm new to anime and have no idea what the best websites to find these would be.

I am specifically looking for vol 2.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Vol.2 is [currently available on Thrift Books](https://www.thriftbooks.com/browse/?b.search=boys%20over%20flowers#b.s=mostPopular-desc&b.p=1&b.pp=30&b.oos&b.tile), a website for second-hand books. They deliver to a bunch of countries and it's a good place for searching for out-of-print titles.

Comment: Sadly i'm looking for the French version. But this helps too!